# Lucene.Net Case Insensitive Keyword Analyzer ReusableTokenStream

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

As the title says, I need a Lucene.Net Case Insensitive Keyword Analyzer.

I've come up with this...

```
using Lucene.Net.Analysis;

namespace LuceneTools
{
  public sealed class LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer :Analyzer
  {
    public override TokenStream TokenStream(System.String fieldName, System.IO.TextReader reader)
    {
        return new LowerCaseFilter(new KeywordTokenizer(reader));
    }

    public override TokenStream ReusableTokenStream(System.String fieldName, System.IO.TextReader reader)
    {
        return new LowerCaseFilter(new KeywordTokenizer(reader));
    }
  }
}
```

Although the code above seems to work, I don't really understand what I should be doing differently with the ReusableTokenStream ? I guess the above is *bad* but I'm not sure how/why or what to do about it.  Perhaps I shouldn't override that at all,but if I don't what happens to code that uses that route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is effectively equivalent to not implementing `ReusableTokenStream`.  Here is the `Analyzer` source code (java):

```
public TokenStream reusableTokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) throws IOException {
    return tokenStream(fieldName, reader);
}
```

So your implementation isn't doing anything worse than the default implementation.

The purpose of `ReuseableTokenStream` is to improve performance by not having to recreate everything every time it's called, generally by attempting to `reset()` the last stream, and falling back on simply calling `tokenStream` if that fails.  Obviously, your implementation doesn't really do that.